# org: Internal link with automatically updating description, is it possible?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I use the `CUSTOM_ID` property for internally linking to headers.
When I insert a link somewhere, I can either:

1. leave its description empty, which results in the buffer showing `#<id>`; or
2. put the header manually as the description, but if I ever change the header the description won't sync to match.

Is it possible to leave the description empty, but have the buffer show the header?
Even if it requires some manual "refresh" or reloading the file (`revert-buffer`) for the descriptions to update, I would be happy.

BTW, I'm using spacemacs, though I don't think it's relevant.

Comment: "... but have the buffer show the header?" - it's unclear to me what you mean by that. Do you mean that the description should be filled in automatically from the header that the link points to?

Comment: @NickD Exactly, as if I put the header in the description by hand.

Comment: Just conceptually I suppose one could write a custom function to walk all links in a buffer, filter for `id:` links and extract the ID substring, use `org-find-entry-with-id` to get the link target, extract the heading and write it back into the description field.